# improper integral equal to proper integral

Tags: calculus

if we let x reach $\infty $ both terms in function $f$ become zero. How it can ever be equal to half of integral on the left.

Any idea how to start working on this problem ?

[image]

Comment: Well, $g(x)$ is $\int_b^\infty$-integrable for $b\in\{2a-1,2a\}$ (prove!), so it boils down to just replacing $f(x)$ with its expression and doing the respective substitutions in the resulting integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f$ and $g$ are continuous in $[1,\infty)$ so the only singularity is at $\infty$.
$$\int_a^{\infty}f(x)\,dx=\lim_{p\to\infty}\int_a^pf(x)\,dx=\lim_{p\to\infty}\left(\int_a^pg(2x-1)\,dx-\int_a^pg(2x)\,dx\right)$$
Then make the substitutions $x\mapsto \frac{x+1}{2}$ and $x\mapsto\frac{x}{2}$ in the first and second integral, respectively. The expression inside the limit becomes
$$\frac 12\left(\int_{2a-1}^{2p-1}g(x)\,dx-\int_{2a}^{2p}g(x)\,dx\right)=\frac 12\left(\int_{2a-1}^{2a}g(x)\,dx-\int_{2p-1}^{2p}g(x)\,dx\right) $$
So we just have to prove that $\lim_{p\to\infty}\int_{2p-1}^{2p}g(x)\,dx=0$. For large enough $x$, $\ln\left(1+\ln(x)\right)<x^{1/5}$, so
$$0<g(x)<\frac{x}{x^{4/3}}x^{1/5}=x^{-2/15} $$
and the result follows by showing that
$$\lim_{p\to\infty}\int_{2p-1}^{2p}x^{-2/15}\,dx=\lim_{p\to\infty}\left(\frac{15}{13}\left((2p)^{13/15}-(2p-1)^{13/15}\right)\right)=0$$